# How can I split a Devise User into two?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sti

I have a very fat User model. I want to separate certain methods out of it and put them in a new model I will create, called Manager that will inherit from User with STI.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 ..
 def user_method
 end
end

class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
 ..
 def manager_method
 end
end
```

I am curious how Devise handles this. Let's say I have a user already, and let's also say the user is a Manager. But when he logs in, the current_user object will be instantiated from User class, right? I assume in true object oriented fashion, Rails would not permit us to access the methods of a child from the instance of a parent class...right?

So what do I need to do to make sure that current_user object is an instance of the class specified in the type column, which is the case with STI in Rails?

Comment: have you tried looking at cancan? if you're planning to use roles, i'd suggest you look into it :) It plays very well with Devise as a bonus

Comment: I looked at it, but my problem is the User model is too fat. I need to split it up. Using a different model would be the best way to do that, I figured...

Comment: i don't think really fat models are THAT bad to warrant an architectural change like that.  I don't know how fat yours are though, so I may be wrong. Another suggestion would be to separate your code into library files, which is included into your user model so you can better organize it. I feel that if cancan can't solve that problem for you, then library files probably would. Just an opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do it like this :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ROLES = ['Admin', 'RoleX', 'RoleY']
  devise :database_authenticatable, :blah
  attr_accessible :email, :blah
  validates :something

  def method
  end
end
```

and for example define class for admin that will inherit from user but will remain separate role in devise.

```
class Admin < User
  def some_method

  end
end
```

Comment: Sure, but my question is "Does `current_user` know about the some_method in Admin? Can I call some method from User.new.some_method?"

Comment: I tested that I cannot. So maybe that answers that. But there has to be a better way of doing this!

Comment: You could do the delegates but it would spaghetti-up your models ;( I think that fat User model, separate models inheriting from User and CanCan::Ability is your destiny.